# Katalon Linux- Unable to get report

Tags: katalon-studio

I have set up Katalon Test Suite on Linux machine.
My use case: I want to email Katalon Report but my report is not getting generated in Katalon.

I have installed different versions and tried with 5.0.1, 5.9.0 and 6.0.1 Version

Report Directory has execution files

Html report file is expected

Comment: Do you use Katalon plugging for Reports?  If not you have to use that. <https://store.katalon.com/manage/products> then chose 'Basic Report'

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something to get Report.

1. Since version 6.1.5, the Report feature has been migrated to Basic Report plugin. install [Basic Report](https://store.katalon.com/product/59/Basic-Report) plugin to use this feature.
2. Currenly, Katalon studio only supports exporting Test Suite Collection reports to HTML format.[Basic Report](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/basic-report.html#features)

Answer (score 0):

Reports are automatically generated for Test **Suite** executions. Make sure you are running your tests inside of a suite.

If you have a single Test **Case**, put it inside of a Test Suite and then execute the TS.